# Rate limiting sends via AWS SNS Topics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have over 5M subscribers to a SNS topic. I want to slowly send the push notifications to these users say at the rate of 20000 per sec. AWS tries to deliver the message to 5M as fast as possible. Is there any way I can slow down the sends ?

Comment: What sort of use-case would have 5m subscribers to a topic? Are they apps or emails?

Comment: Why do you want to slow down?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - they're push notification contacts.

Comment: @Kannaiyan - coz if a lot of people open the app together, the app slows down coz the load suddenly increases on our servers.

Comment: @Ankit as mentioned in the answer, https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/ is the right way to handle the flow control rate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration setting for Amazon SNS to limit the speed of notifications.

You would probably need to create separate SNS topics and send to each in turn (with a delay).

If you are doing some form of marketing to mobile apps, you could consider using [Amazon Pinpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/) instead.